# Searching a value in a string in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, magento, magento-1.9

I have a website running on Magento(1.9) and have a requirement to find out the average time a customer take to buy the same product again and the percentage of customers who have bought the same product.

Orders table(Sales_flat_order) - Contains the order details
    Columns - order_id,Created_date,Customer_email

Items table(Sales_Flat_Order_item) - Items in a particular order,If a user buy 6 Items then the items table will have 6 entries with the same order_id.
    Columns - items_id,Order_id(FK),item_sku(different for diff. Products)

Below is the sample data which i have joined orders and items tables for a specific customer filtered by email id.

For example the order_id "92224" there are 4 rows means there are 4 items purchased in that order and the item_sku refers the item name / its unique ID.

Now i want to find out the Average time taken for to buy the same product again.So in the order "98651" the user have purchased the product items_sku("2996") which was there in the first order.So the average time will be the date difference between those 2 orders.

Below are the difficulties i'm facing,

1) Since each order can contains multiple products how i can compare the row of items with the previous order items.I have tried with LIKE & ILIKE and it doesn't seems to work and tried to use STR_AGG(item_sku,',') with LIKE but have not find any result.

2) Not only for a particular customer ,this need to be done for each and every customer.

```
Order_id     Order_date         Item_sku
92224   "2016-11-11 17:18:15"   "3001"
92224   "2016-11-11 17:18:15"   "2933"
92224   "2016-11-11 17:18:15"   "2992-config"
92224   "2016-11-11 17:18:15"   "2996"
94926   "2016-11-25 10:01:30"   "3008"
98651   "2016-12-14 18:11:16"   "2992-config"
98651   "2016-12-14 18:11:16"   "2996"
99645   "2016-12-20 13:00:34"   "3001"
99645   "2016-12-20 13:00:34"   "2933"
114578  "2017-02-28 15:32:54"   "2931"
114578  "2017-02-28 15:32:54"   "0294"
114578  "2017-02-28 15:32:54"   "0297"
114578  "2017-02-28 15:32:54"   "0296"
114578  "2017-02-28 15:32:54"   "2992-config"
131754  "2017-05-15 17:23:35"   "3296"
131968  "2017-05-16 18:30:52"   "3300"
133186  "2017-05-22 14:03:07"   "3004"
133186  "2017-05-22 14:03:07"   "3069-bio"
133186  "2017-05-22 14:03:07"   "3421-bio-config"
137484  "2017-06-13 14:07:28"   "3605"
137484  "2017-06-13 14:07:28"   "3604"
141709  "2017-07-03 16:20:30"   "3603"
141709  "2017-07-03 16:20:30"   "3606"
141709  "2017-07-03 16:20:30"   "2936"
141709  "2017-07-03 16:20:30"   "3422-bio"
141977  "2017-07-04 16:31:37"   "2936"
145194  "2017-07-17 15:22:41"   "3603"
145194  "2017-07-17 15:22:41"   "3604"
151651  "2017-08-11 11:43:38"   "3809"
161334  "2017-09-14 15:53:30"   "3670"
161334  "2017-09-14 15:53:30"   "3604"
161334  "2017-09-14 15:53:30"   "3603"
```

Any guidance will be of great help.I'm using PostgreSQL as my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about magento, but this is how I would solve this in postgres, given your input data:

```
SELECT item_sku, avg(elapsed_s) as avg_s
FROM (
  select order_id, 
         order_date, 
         item_sku, 
         extract(epoch from (order_date - lag(order_date) 
            OVER (partition by item_sku order by order_date))) as elapsed_s
  FROM orders
) sub
WHERE elapsed_s IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY item_sku
;
  item_sku   |    avg
-------------+-----------
 2933        |   3354139
 2936        |     87067
 2992-config | 4705639.5
 2996        |   2854381
 3001        |   3354139
 3603        |   3152790
 3604        |   4020781
(7 rows)
```

This is the average time, in seconds, between purchasing the same item.  In the inner query, we use the lag window function, partitioned by item_sku to compare the current row to the previous entry for this item.  The outer query just groups by the item_sku.

If you are adding multiple users, you would simply change the `partition by` clause to `partition by user_id, item_sku` and then group by both user_id and item_sku.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt response, this query will only check for the previous order right? Means whether the customer have bought the same product in the just previous order?

Comment: This will get the difference between when the customer buys a product and then buys the same product again, no matter how many orders came between the two orders.  Does the customer have to buy the product again in the very next order?

Comment: No, Not to be in the second order.Thanks for the reply:) It really helped.

Comment: So what is the user ordered the same items in more than 2, means in 5 consecutive orders the user bought the same product, So using lag will not get the exact result right?

Comment: `lag` will figure out the difference in time between two consecutive orders of the same product.  We figure out the difference between every order of the same product and use `avg` with `group by` to figure out the average time between orders.  2992-config was ordered three times, which is why the avg_s is not a whole number.

Answer (score 2):

@Jeremy actually presents a good routine with the exception that the results is in elapsed seconds. However, that may not be the most useful format. Rather than using epoch you can use date subtraction and intervals directly.

```
select item_sku
     , extract('days' from average_time) || ' days ' ||  extract('hour' from average_time) || ' hours' average_time
  from (    
        select item_sku,avg(intv) average_time   
          from (
                select order_date, 
                       item_sku, 
                       (order_date - lag(order_date) 
                                     OVER (partition by item_sku order by order_date)) as intv
                  FROM sales_flat_order_item
               ) intv_diff
         where intv is not null
         group by item_sku
         order by item_sku) avg_time;
```

The outer most query merely formats the the result to days and hours. Without it the results may appear (and do) to the fractional seconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot , But this query will only check for the previous order right?Means whether the customer have bought the same product in the just previous order?